# Angularjs ui-grid exporterPdfCustomFormatter function fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

The example code for angularjs ui-grid [PDF exporter from Tutorial Lesson 206](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data) works great on the official page. When I copy the code and run it ... or run it in their Plunker ... it briefly opens a tab for the PDF output and then closes the tab.

After much debugging, I discovered that removing the `exporterPdfCustomFormatter` setting solves the problem.  In fact, I can set that to either of the other 2 examples in the [API reference](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions#exporterPdfFooter) (simple text or column definition), but setting it to any function (such as required for page numbers) fails. There is a discrepancy between the use of `pageCount` here and the official pdfmake site, but that turns out to be irrelevant: ANY function fails.

I don't understand why this is working on the official site, but what appears to be identical code doesn't work for me or their Plunker.

Comment: Be sure to include the pdfmake.js file, as well as its vfs_fonts.js dependency. More info here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem. To get this to work remove the exporterPdfCustomFormatter from app.js

```
//exporterPdfCustomFormatter: function ( docDefinition ) {
//      docDefinition.styles.headerStyle = { fontSize: 22, bold: true }; 
//      docDefinition.styles.footerStyle = { fontSize: 10, bold: true }; 
//      return docDefinition;
//    },
```